# Как добавить \ в строку в Java

Tags: java, символы

Пишу программу которая бы создавала bat-ник для копирования файлов с одной папки в другую. И, увы, столкнулся с проблемой когда надо вставить символ `\`. Пример кода:

```
String text =  "COPY "  + where + " "+ kuda + " "+ "/H " + "\" + "@pause";
```

Как можно вписать этот символ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> "\"
> ```

Экранировать надо спецсимволы:

```
"\\"
```